# цикл for i:=1 to 6 do из паскаля в C++

Tags: c++, pascal

Здравствуйте
В паскале можно сделать:

```pascal
for i:=1 to 6 do
```

и так далее
Как такое же провернуть в C++?

Comment: На сайте при поиске по слову "цикл/ы С++" даётся более 1500 ответов, почти каждый из которых содержит примеры. Автор вопроса настолько презирает участников сообщества, что не готов потратить пять минут на поиски нужного ему ответа, считая должными участников тратить свое время на ответ.

Comment: @Arkady: на подавляющее большинство вопросов на SO, можно ответить, потратив пять минут на поиски. Потому что кто-то уже задал вопрос, люди ответили, поисковик проиндексировал. Если вы знаете точный дубликат этого вопроса, тогда  закройте как дубликат. Про простоту вопроса: я вот Паскаль не знаю и не смогу сказать: следует использовать `int`, `size_t`, `int32_t` или какой другой тип в аналогичном цикле на С++. Ещё бы стоило упомянуть range-for-цикл из c++11—если всю коллекцию цикл обходит, то можно и не думать о типах индекса—к примеру, в Питоне использование  индексов в цикле это ошибка часто

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i <=6; ++i) и так далее
```

Answer (score -2):

А мне больше нравится так: =)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
```